# How to set and read data to Angular reactive nestled form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to iterate on HTML trought two arrays.But somehow I can't access to the second array in it.
Here is the data:

```
{
    "id": "bankloandeal@test.ba",
    "businessType": "",
    "phone": "555333",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "webSiteUrl": "http://www/",
    "defaultCurrencyIso": "USD",
    "isPublished": "false",
    "publicUrl": null,
    "address": {
        "type": "home",
        "postOfficeBox": "",
        "street": "new broj 3",
        "city": "new york",
        "state": "Somewhere",
        "countryOrRegion": "Somewhere",
        "postalCode": "72000"
    },
    "businessHours": [
        {
            "day": "monday",
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "start": "08:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "11:00:00.0000000"
                },
                {
                    "start": "12:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "17:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "tuesday",
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "start": "08:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "17:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "wednesday",
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "start": "08:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "17:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "thursday",
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "start": "08:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "17:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "friday",
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "start": "08:00:00.0000000",
                    "end": "17:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "saturday",
            "timeSlots": []
        },
        {
            "day": "sunday",
            "timeSlots": []
        }
    ],
    "schedulingPolicy": {
        "timeSlotInterval": "PT30M",
        "minimumLeadTime": "P1D",
        "maximumAdvance": "P365D",
        "sendConfirmationsToOwner": true,
        "allowStaffSelection": true
    },
    "displayName": "bank loan deal"
}
```

I'm trying to enter to businessHours and then to timeSlots.

[Displaying days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4v6v.png)

with this code

```
<div formArrayName="businessHours">
    <div *ngFor="let businessDays of booking.get('businessHours')['controls'];let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="text" formControlName="day" class="clr-input" readonly>
        <ng-container formArrayName="timeSlots">
            <div *ngFor="let time of businessDays;let j = index;" [formGroupName]="j">
                {{j+1}}
                <input class="clr-input" type="text" formControlName="start">
                <input class="clr-input" type="text" formControlName="end">
            </div>
        </ng-container>
        <clr-icon shape="plus"></clr-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also when I add to the second ngFor same like in first only with timeSlots I get an error that its undefined control.
And also I get the error message:

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Also when I press submit button on this form I get this data saved but I can't show it on the front part.

This is how I create the form

```
  createForm(): void {
    this.booking = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [''],
      businessType: [''],
      phone: [''],
      email: [''],
      webSiteUrl: [''],
      defaultCurrencyIso: [''],
      publicUrl: [''],
      type: [],
      city: [''],
      street: [''],
      countryOrRegion: [''],
      state: [''],
      postalCode: [''],
      businessHours: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      timeSlotInterval: [''],
      minimumLeadTime: [''],
      maximumAdvance: [''],
      sendConfirmationsToOwner: true,
      allowStaffSelection: true,
      displayName: [''],
      isPublished: []
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isaxsa sorry for no design.. no time for that really.. In this demo I can't also get the days but in my version I can.. only the problem is timeSlots